# "Error: Unable to access jarfile" if try'd to start from .sh script

Tags: java, bash, jar, sh, chmod

I have the following problem: I would like to have a .sh file that starts a jar file so I have created one with nano and added the following:

```
java -jar myjarfile.jar
```

But Java gives me the following error "*Error: Unable to access jarfile myjarfile.jar*" so I tried to start it directly from the console with the same command. This works without problems so I checked the rights:

```
chmod 775 myjarfile.jar
chmod 775 start.sh
```

But I have exactly the same result. So I tried it with the root account but that did not help either. So slowly I'm a little bit desperate because I can not think of it anymore...

System information:

```
Linux version 4.9.0-8-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u6 (2018-10-08)

java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

***Thanks for any answer :)***

Comment: The path to JAR is relative. Are you sure the current working directory is correct?

Comment: Also, are your PATH and CLASSPATH exported? Are you setting them in your script? try `ls myjarfile.jar` on the preceeding line.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yes is right it will also work if i execute the command in console from same directory and if i write the path directly also "/home/user/jarfile/myjarfile.jar" it don't work

Comment: @PaulHodges Same answere: Yes is right it will also work if i execute the command in console from same directory and if i write the path directly also "/home/user/jarfile/myjarfile.jar" it don't work

Comment: @SpieleArena can you post the script you're trying to run?  That might be useful for figuring out what the problem is.